# Why doesn't String toCharArray use Arrays.copyOf?

Tags: java

In the JDK source of `java.lang.String.toCharArray`, it doesn't use `Arrays.copyOf` to implement this and it says:

> Cannot use Arrays.copyOf because of class initialization order issues

What are the "class initialization order issues"?

```
public char[] toCharArray() {
    // Cannot use Arrays.copyOf because of class initialization order issues
    char result[] = new char[value.length];
    System.arraycopy(value, 0, result, 0, value.length);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: where do you initialize `value`? do you use copy constructor? see http://www.i-programmer.info/programmer-puzzles/168-c/2845-a-problem-of-order-constructor-initilization.html

Comment: @AsfK I guess the OP take a part of the JDK source code. (not a MCVE?)

Comment: To be honest, without significant analysis @BrianGoetz might be the only person who could answer.

Comment: @Asfk I think `Arrays.copyOf` means use `Arrays.copyOf(value , value.length)` to implement .

Comment: @shaoyihe, you're right, I got it wrong. I not familiar with this method but when I'm change value to be char[] it's working, maybe there's a type mismatch issue..

Answer (score 45):

I did a test about this. Following is the works I've done:

1. Get the source code of `String.java` from JDK.
2. Modify its `toCharArray` method to use `Arrays.copyOf`.

   like this:

   ```
   public char[] toCharArray() {
       // Cannot use Arrays.copyOf because of class initialization order issues
       /*char result[] = new char[value.length];
       System.arraycopy(value, 0, result, 0, value.length);
       return result;*/
       return Arrays.copyOf(value, value.length);
   }
   ```
3. compile this modified `String`, and save it back into JRE's rt.jar.
4. Write a simple HelloWorld Java code.
5. Compile & run the code using `java` program.

And finally, I get this:

```
PS D:\> & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\bin\java.exe' StringTest
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.remove(Hashtable.java:491)
    at java.lang.System.initProperties(Native Method)
    at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(System.java:1166)
```

We can see there is truly an `initialization` error. And because `System.initProperties` is a native method, I can not check its code.

However, We can make a guess why this could happen:

1. `System.initProperties` needs to handle some Strings while it initializes system properties.
2. And while doing initialize, it might invoke `String.toCharArray` to get char arrays from those strings.
3. Strings invoke `Arrays.copyOf`, but at this point & this time, `Arrays` has not been loaded / initialized.
4. Differing from running Java code, the native code would not ask for a `class initializing request` (I'm not sure about this, please let me know if I'm wrong!!), and which will lead to a `NullPointerException` and make VM exit.

---

2018.04.10 Update.

I'd like to Thank @Radiodef for his hint. But when I tried going into the C++ codes, I was stopped by so many execution paths which I could not handle without running or debugging the OpenJDK's JVM.

And then, I changed my strategy. I did some more test based on above which I had done for a few days.

This time, I'm not going to use `Arrays.copyOf` with `String.toCharArray`, instead, I attempt to find out which codes will invoke `toCharArray` method while JVM initializing.

So I modify `String`, add two static variables to it:

```
public static int count;
public static Throwable[] logs = new Throwable[10000];
```

In which `count` is used to count the invocation of `toCharArray`, `logs` is used to keep those invocation's stack traces.

In `toCharArray` method:

```
public char[] toCharArray() {
    if (count < logs.length) {
        try {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            logs[count] = e;
        }
    }
    count++;

    // Cannot use Arrays.copyOf because of class initialization order issues
    char result[] = new char[value.length];
    System.arraycopy(value, 0, result, 0, value.length);
    return result;
}
```

After done those, I compile `String` again and save it back into rt.jar.

Then, I write a test program to print `count` and invocation stack traces out:

```
Class<String> clazz = String.class;
Field count = clazz.getDeclaredField("count");
System.out.println(count.getInt(null));
Field logs = clazz.getDeclaredField("logs");
Throwable[] arr = (Throwable[]) logs.get(null);
for (Throwable e : arr) {
    if (e != null)
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

We can not access `String.count & String.logs` directly in our codes, as compiler (`javac`) does not recognize these fields and will cause a compile error. That's why I'm using reflect-way to do this.

Run the program we've just written, and the results will be:

```
525
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at java.lang.String.toCharArray(String.java:2889)
    at sun.nio.cs.ext.GBK.initb2c(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.ext.GBK.newDecoder(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringCoding$StringDecoder.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringCoding$StringDecoder.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:414)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:479)
    at java.lang.System.initProperties(Native Method)
    at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(Unknown Source)

......

java.lang.RuntimeException
    at java.lang.String.toCharArray(String.java:2889)
    at sun.net.www.ParseUtil.encodePath(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

What a long invocation list. However it is clearer than the previous test. We can clearly see which classes invoke `toCharArray`.

Comment: [The native code can be found here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/native/java/lang/System.c#l167), if anyone wants to keep looking around in it. The exception at [`Hashtable` line 491](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Hashtable.java#491) suggests that a key which is `null` is being passed to the `Properties.remove` method somehow.